# How to load resources from within a jar file loaded in a java application?

Tags: java

So, I have a main application that should load a jar that contains code and other resources (i.e.: jar files, text files, java properties etc.). I use:

```
JarFile jar  = new JarFile(jar);
Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();

int URLsize = 1;
while (entries.hasMoreElements())
    if (entries.nextElement().getName().startsWith("foo/bar/foobar"))
        URLsize++;

entries = jar.entries();

URL[] urls = new URL[URLsize];
urls[0] = patch.toURI().toURL();

int count = 1;
while (entries.hasMoreElements())
{
    JarEntry nextElement = entries.nextElement();
    if (nextElement.getName().startsWith("foo/bar/foobar"))
    {               
        urls[count] = new URL("jar:file:/"+ jar.getAbsolutePath() + "!/" + nextElement.getName());

        count++;
    }
}
```

to load the resources of the jar, and an URLClassLoader plus some reflection to get all resources together and execute the jar's main class, like this:

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader (urls);
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);

Class<?> jarC = Class.forName ("foo.bar.barfoo.Main", true, loader);
Constructor<?> cons = jarC.getConstructor(String.class, String.class, Properties.class, Properties.class, String[].class);
Object instance = cons.newInstance (systemPath, programPath, config, some_data, args);

Method method = jarC.getMethod ("Main");

method.invoke (instance);
```

Now the problem is that inside the loaded jar's code when I try to load a bunch of files (resources) from a package inside the jar (e.g.: /foo/bar/foobar) it throws a `NullPointerException`.

```
private static InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resource) {       
        try {       
            return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resource).openStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

That's how I try to get the package that than gets parsed with a `BufferedReader` and an `InputStreamReader` to get the names of each resource inside the package.
Okay, maybe a bit too detailed (this is just one way I use the `getResourceAsStream` method), but I hope I made myself understood, the `ContextClassLoader` doesn't contain the resources I loaded in the application that runs this jar within itself, so what do I need to do to get those from within the loaded jar?

EDIT: Calling the `getResourceAsStream` method:

```
private static List<String> getResourceFiles(String path) throws IOException {
    List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<>();

    try (
            InputStream in = getResourceAsStream(path);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
        String resource;

        while ((resource = br.readLine()) != null) {
            filenames.add(resource);
        }
    }

    return filenames;
}
```

And where the `getResourceFiles` method is called:

```
List<String> names = Foo.getResourceFiles("/foo/bar/foobar");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even do all this? Why not just add URL to JAR to the URLClassLoader?

E.g.

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new File(jar).toURI().toURL());
```

Also you should probably make that URLClassLoader have your current classloader as parent, e.g.

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new File(jar).toURI().toURL(), Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

Comment: Since I don't see any calls to getResourceAsStream in the code you've posted I can't say for sure what is the culprit. Maybe you just provide a bad name of a resource. Can you show the code that actually calls getResourceAsStream?

Comment: It's quite an inception, I'll summarize it in a second and I'll edit the post

Comment: I doubt I call the wrong resource since I tried getting the file in the main application and it works with that ContextLoader.

Comment: And what is /foo/bar/foobar? Looks like you expect it to be a text file with filenames in it or something like that - but is it actually a folder?

Comment: I'm not expecting a file, it is intendedly a package/folder out of which the code should pull a list of file names.

Comment: This is the actual string that's there: `"/com/daskrr/mcp/patch/file/plugin"`

Comment: So I figured a little bit more, the thing that doesn't work and/or I don't know how to figure out is listing all files in a classpath resource folder when the `URLClassLoader` is used and set as `ContextClassLoader` (with the class' loader as parent as you suggested)

Comment: No, it happens in `getResourceAsStream` at `return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resource).openStream();`.

Comment: I solved it with a workaround, I made a file called "classpath" and wrote down all the resources the folder was containing and got their paths from there. (Should I mark it as solved?)

Comment: So null-pointer happens in getResourceAsStream, where you pass what? Names obtained from Foo.getResourceFiles("/foo/bar/foobar")? You have to prepend "/foo/bar/foobar/" to those names. Imagine you have file /foo/bar/foobar/baz.txt there. Foo.getResourceFiles("/foo/bar/foobar") will return list with "baz.txt". getResourceAsStream("baz.txt") will fail because it should be getResourceAsStream("/foo/bar/foobar/baz.txt").